# Reshape pandas dataframe and work with columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have dataset:

```
dat = {'Block': ['blk_-105450231192318816', 'blk_-1076549517733373559', 'blk_-1187723472581877455', 'blk_-1385756122847916710',  'blk_-1470784088028862059'], 'Seq': ['13 13 13 15',' 15 13 13', '13 13 15', '13 13 15 13', '13'], 'Time' : ['1257712532.0 1257712532.0 1257712532.0 1257712532.0','1257712533.0 1257712534.0 1257712534.0','1257712533.0 1257712533.0 1257712533.0','1257712532.0 1257712532.0 1257712532.0 1257712534.0','1257712535.0']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = dat)
```

Block is id. Seq is id. Time is time in unix format.
I want to change columns or create new columns.

1)I need to join Seq and Time columns by index of elements in two columns.

2)After i want to get delta of Time column(next element - previous) and first element set to zero.

And in the end write in file rows from different block, but witch have same Seq-id.
I want to solve this problem by pandas methods

I tried to solve it by dictionary, but this way is complicated.

```py
dict_block = dict((key, []) for key in np.unique(df.Block))
for idx, row in enumerate(seq):
    block = df.Block[idx]
    dict_seq = dict((key, []) for key in np.unique(row.split(' ')))
    for idy, key in enumerate(row.split(' ')):
        item = df.Time[idx].split(' ')[idy]
        dict_seq[key].append(item)
    dict_block[block].append(dict_seq)
```

1)For example:

```
blk_-105450231192318816 : 
    13: 1257712532.0, 1257712532.0, 1257712532.0
    15: 1257712532.0
```

2)For example:

```
blk_-105450231192318816 : 
    13: 0, (1257712532.0 - 1257712532.0) = 0, (1257712532.0 - 1257712532.0) = 0
    15: 0
```

Output for dictionary try:

```
{'blk_-105450231192318816': 
[{'13': ['1257712532.0', '1257712532.0','1257712532.0'],
'15': ['1257712532.0']}],
'blk_-1076549517733373559': 
[{'13': ['1257712534.0', '1257712534.0'],
'15': ['1257712533.0']}],
'blk_-1187723472581877455': 
[{'13': ['1257712533.0', '1257712533.0'],
'15': ['1257712533.0']}],
'blk_-1385756122847916710': 
[{'13': ['1257712532.0',
'1257712532.0',
'1257712534.0'],
'15': ['1257712532.0']}],
'blk_-1470784088028862059': 
[{'13': ['1257712535.0']}]}
```

Summary:

I want solve next points by pandas, numpy methods:

1) Group columns

2) Get delta of time(t1-t0)

Waiting for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Working with dicts

If you prefer working with dictionaries, you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and custom methods where you do your tricks with the dictionaries.

`df` is the sample dataframe you provided. Here I've made two methods. I hope the code is clear enough to be understandable.

```
def grouping(x):
    """Make a dictionary combining 'Seq' and 'Time' columns.

    'Seq' elements are the keys, 'Time' are the values. 'Time' elements
    corresponding to the same key are stored in a list.
    """
    #splitting the string and make it numeric
    keys = list(map(int, x['Seq'].split()))
    times = list(map(float, x['Time'].split()))

    #building the result dictionary.
    res = {}
    for i, k in enumerate(keys):
        try:
            res[k].append(times[i])
        except KeyError:
            res[k] = [times[i]]

    return res    


def timediffs(x):
    """Make a dictionary starting from 'GroupedSeq' column, which can
    be created with the grouping function.

    It contains the difference between the times of each key.
    """
    ddt = x['GroupedSeq']
    res = {}
    #iterating over the dictionary to calculate the differences.
    for k, v in ddt.items():
        res[k] = [0.0] + [t1 - t0 for t0, t1 in zip(v[:-1], v[1:])]
    return res  

df['GroupedSeq'] = df.apply(grouping, axis=1)
df['difftimes'] = df.apply(timediffs, axis=1)
```

What `apply` does here is to apply the function on each row. The result is stored in a new column of the dataframe. Now `df` contains two new column, you can drop the original `'Seq'` and `Time` columns if you wish, by doing: `df.drop(['Seq', 'Time'], axis=1, inplace=True)`. In the end, `df` looks like:

```
                      Block                                            grouped                         difftimes
0   blk_-105450231192318816  {13: [1257712532.0, 1257712532.0, 1257712532.0...  {13: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 15: [0.0]}
1  blk_-1076549517733373559  {15: [1257712533.0], 13: [1257712534.0, 125771...       {15: [0.0], 13: [0.0, 0.0]}
2  blk_-1187723472581877455  {13: [1257712533.0, 1257712533.0], 15: [125771...       {13: [0.0, 0.0], 15: [0.0]}
3  blk_-1385756122847916710  {13: [1257712532.0, 1257712532.0, 1257712534.0...  {13: [0.0, 0.0, 2.0], 15: [0.0]}
4  blk_-1470784088028862059                               {13: [1257712535.0]}                       {13: [0.0]}
```

As you can see, here `pandas` itself is used only to apply the custom methods, but inside those methods there is normal python code at work.

---

#### Solution 2: No dictionaries, more Pandas

Pandas itself is not very useful if you are storing list or dicts in the dataframe. So I propose an alternative a solution without dictionaries. I use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in combination with `apply` to perform operations on selected rows based on their values.
`groupby` selects a subsample of the dataframe based on the values of one or more columns: all rows with the same values in those columns are grouped, and a method or action is performed on this subsample.

Again, `df` is the sample dataframe you provided.

```
df1 = df.copy() #working on a copy, not really needed but I wanted to preserve the original

##splitting the string and make it a numeric list using apply
df1['Seq'] = df1['Seq'].apply(lambda x : list(map(int, x.split())))
df1['Time'] = df1['Time'].apply(lambda x : list(map(float, x.split())))

#for each index in 'Block', unnest the list in 'Seq' making it a secodary index. 
df2 = df1.groupby('Block').apply(lambda x : pd.DataFrame([[e] for e in x['Time'].iloc[0]], index=x['Seq'].tolist()))
#resetting index and renaming column names created by pandas
df2 = df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Seq', 0:'Time'})

#custom method to store the differences between times.
def timediffs(x):
    x['tdiff'] = x['Time'].diff().fillna(0.0)
    return x

df3 = df2.groupby(['Block', 'Seq']).apply(timediffs)
```

The final `df3` is:

```
                       Block      Seq          Time  tdiff
0    blk_-105450231192318816       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
1    blk_-105450231192318816       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
2    blk_-105450231192318816       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
3    blk_-105450231192318816       15  1.257713e+09    0.0
4   blk_-1076549517733373559       15  1.257713e+09    0.0
5   blk_-1076549517733373559       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
6   blk_-1076549517733373559       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
7   blk_-1187723472581877455       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
8   blk_-1187723472581877455       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
9   blk_-1187723472581877455       15  1.257713e+09    0.0
10  blk_-1385756122847916710       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
11  blk_-1385756122847916710       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
12  blk_-1385756122847916710       15  1.257713e+09    0.0
13  blk_-1385756122847916710       13  1.257713e+09    2.0
14  blk_-1470784088028862059       13  1.257713e+09    0.0
```

As you can see, no dictionaries inside the dataframe. You have repetitions in columns `'Block'` and `'Seq'`, but that's unavoidable.

Comment: method "timediffs" is slow:
on 10000 rows 8s,
on 100000 rows 1m 10s,
on 1000000 rows 30m+.
groupby work fast. Do you have any idea to optimize "timediffs" method?

Comment: @savchart Not really. You could try by using a dict compehenstion to build `res`, with the nested list comprehension. Will be less readable but a bit faster. I think however solution 2 will still be faster.